# Redirection to other directories

Tags: bash, unix, oracle-enterprise-linux

My /home directory is having very less memory. But some of my programs which are running in production will create dynamic files in '/home' directory.

The problem is if it reaches to 100% then my program doesn't work. So I have to manually go and delete the files or copy the files.

**So rather than doing that I want to redirect the files from '/home' to '/tmp' directory in unix by default.**

Please give me some thoughts.

Comment: fix your filesystem or your programs instead of looking for work arounds.

Comment: @123: thanks for your reply. Actually it's not my code, I am using firefox headless browser. So I can't change it.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two ways to do:

- if you can config your program to export files to other dir, do this.
- if you cannot do anything on the program, you can create a cron job, remove/cp those files automatically

Comment: ^1. The output path is very likely configurable.

Comment: @hek2mgl now I know the meaning of `^`...!

Comment: You mean *a literal 1 at the start of the line*? :D

Comment: @Kent: Thanks Kent for your reply. I can't do it through cron job aswell, because here directories are created by firefox in '/tmp'. The biggest problem is it will keep on using that directory which is created, so the size will be keep on increasing.

Answer (score 0):

If the program creates files under it's own directory, you can create a symlink:

```
# Create directory in /tmp
mkdir /tmp/myprog

# Set permissions
chown "${USER}:${USER}" /tmp/myprog
chmod -R o-x /tmp/myprog

# Create symlink at /home/myprog
ln -s /tmp/myprog "${HOME}/myprog"
```

Comment: I understood the files were written to `$HOME` directly no sub-dir.  But if I am wrong, you answer is the most straightforward solution. But it should not be counted as a question then, IMO. :-)

Comment: Besides that, the question is far off-topic :)

Comment: I've flagged it. Question and answers can be transferred to superuser.com

Comment: @hek2mgl : Thanks for your reply, actually as I explained in previous comment to Kent Firefox can't create that symlinks.